# How to use Session with the Nancy Razor ViewEngine

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

I'm using the RazorViewEngine for [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org) and I would like to have a ViewBag like object where I can store dynamic properties.  Although not ideal, I decided that Session state would suffice for my purposes.  I've enabled CookieBasedSession in my Bootstrapper's ApplicationStartup method, and I added a BeforeRequest Pipeline method to set the Session variable. However, I don't know how to retrieve the value in my View.  Is this possible, without adding the Session variable to a model?  Is the Session state only meant to be accessed in modules?

(cross posted from the nancy-fx forum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of right now you will need to pass in the values though your view model. There is no direct access to the session state from inside a view